# More than 30 characters for characteristic values in SAP ECC in Variant configuration

Tags: configuration, character, variant, sap-erp

I need to be able to use more than 30 characters to describe characteristic values in Variant Configuration in SAP ECC.
I think in S/4HANA the input is not limited to 30 characters anymore, but currently, we are using ECC.
Can someone help with ways to overcome this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use SAP Note 554086 for implementing this

[Modification: Length of characteristics or characteristic values > 30](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/554086)

However it requires modification of many of standard dictionary objects, and I do not advise to do so unless highly critical. SAP explicitly says in the note that it withdraws itself from any regular support after implementation, only the paid one.